# Bug in sklearn r2_score (or am I going insane?)

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn

I've been surprised by the results of what I've been getting from the r2_score by sklearn. I'm interested to know if this is a bug, or if I'm going crazy.

I've got, what seems to be, a pretty decently performing and extremely simple linear regression model, and makes predictions that are pretty strongly related to the predicted variable. And yet, the R2 score, when computed by sklearn, is negative and not even close to 1. Isn't this weird? I would have expected it to be around 0.25 (this is what I get from statsmodels with the exact same model).

```
In [203]: scipy.stats.pearsonr(lr.predict(X_train[['ind1', 'ind2']]), X_train['depv'])
Out[203]: (0.50583845705181996, 0.0)

In [204]: r2_score(lr.predict(X_train[['ind1', 'ind2']]), X_train['depv'])
Out[204]: -1.9081957833186149
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the correct responses need to go before the predictions. Duh :-)